# Transform/Convert exception type

Tags: mule

I define a flow. It publishes a Web Service with CXF, exchange-pattern: request-response. The Service defines/throws exception type: CAEService_Exception.  The web service implementation is almost a dummy. The ws request is processed by other message processors in the flow.  During the flow, other components or the ESB itself could throw different exceptions, e.g. ConnectionException, ApplicatOneException, or CompnentTwoException what forever. 
In such case, it is important to throw only (business exception) the CAEService_Exception to the client!
 How to get(catch) the different exceptions, and how to process/handle them so that the CXF module throws CAEService_Exception to client?

Thanks for your advice!
Regards
Dianlong

```xml
<flow name="CAEService" doc:name="CAEService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="${http.host.inbound}/ebiz/ws/CAEService" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
        <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="org.mule.j2a.ws.cae.CAEService"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="org.mule.j2a.ws.cae.CAEServiceImpl" doc:name="Java"/> 
    <flow-ref name="Fest_ERPs" doc:name="Sub Flow with transformers, call other services, etc."/>

    <!-- exceptions -->

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a choice-exception-strategy to catch the different ones.

eg

```
<flow name="Sample_Flow">
...
<choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy"/>
    <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy"/>
</choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

and then throw something else to the client in there respecive implementatinos

```
<catch-exception-strategy name="Catch_Exception_Strategy">
   -- do you stuff
</catch-exception-strategy>
```